# How are the dimensions of the rref matrix multiplied by its transpose determined?

Tags: linear-algebra

Could anyone explain how to arrive at the solution for Problem 7e here? 
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/assignments/MIT18_06S10_pset3_s10_soln.pdf

After more than half an hour of trying various things, I still don't understand how the values and dimensions for the last row of rref(R'R) was obtained.

I have that the bottom right corner of R'R is F'F (dim (n-r)x(n-r)) plus a zero matrix (dim (m-r)x(m-r)), but have no idea how they arrived at 0 (dim (m-r)x(n-r)) for that corner for both R'R and rref(R'R).

Comment: While the problem may be clear to you've introduced a few notations with no clear explanation.  Presumably you are thinking of blocks within the reduced row echelon form of a a matrix.  A few more sentences explaining what $R$ and $m,n,r$ mean would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, there is a typo. The matrix should be
$$R^\top R = \begin{bmatrix}I & F \\ F^\top & F^\top F\end{bmatrix}.$$

Their RREF is correct though. Performing row operations to eliminate the lower-left "$F^\top$" will cancel out the $F^\top F$ as well. (This is essentially subtracting $F^\top[I \quad F]$ from the bottom row.)